# MYSQL оператор IN и несколько полей

Tags: mysql, sql

Мне нужно использовать оператор `IN` в запросе для поиска строк с определенными значениями `PRIMARY` поля, все просто:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE some_id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Но что делать, к примеру, когда ключ `PRIMARY` состоит из нескольких полей? Как использовать оператор `IN` для нескольких полей? Требуется конструкция вроде выдуманной этой

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE some_id1, some_id2 IN ( (1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5) )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

можно группировать столбцы в конструкции `(a, b, ...) in ((...), (...))`. пример:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9809/1)

**MySQL 5.5 Schema Setup**:

```
create table t (x int, y int, z int);

insert into t values
   (1, 1, 0)
  ,(2, 2, 1)
  ,(1, 3, 2)
  ,(2, 4, 3)  
  ,(1, 1, 4)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from t
where (x, y) in ((1, 1), (2, 2))
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9809/1/0)**:

```
| x | y | z |
|---|---|---|
| 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 4 |
```

Answer (score 1):

А что мешает использовать оператор AND?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE some_id1 IN (1,2,3,4,5) AND some_id2 IN (1,2,3,4,5);
```

Если нужно четкое сопоставление уникального ключа, тогда этот запрос нужно генерировать например в php:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (some_id1 = 1 AND some_id2 = 1) OR (some_id1 = 2 AND some_id2 = 2);
```

Comment: Первый вариант не то. Второй вариант понятен, но я думал есть более красивое решение (навроде как сделано INSERT INTO ... VALUES ...) или хак какой-либо.